# MSBuild cant find resgen.exe

Tags: sdk, msbuild

I have a VM machine where I copied over the SDK files and path, went to the registry and added the keys to the registry, but I keep getting the error that `resgen.exe` cannot be found:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1835,9): 
error MSB3091: Task failed because "resgen.exe" was not found, or the correct 
Microsoft Windows SDK is not installed. The task is looking for "resgen.exe" 
in the"bin" subdirectory beneath the location specified in the Installation Folder 
value of the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\
Windows\v7.0A. You may be able to solve the problem by doing one of the following:  
1) Install the Microsoft Windows SDK.  
2) Install Visual Studio 2010.  
3) Manually set the above registry key to the correct location.  
4) Pass the correct location into the "ToolPath" parameter of the task.
```

I looked in the folder `Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A` and copied over the `resgen.exe` in practically every single net folder including the bin, but it keeps telling me that `resgen.exe` cannot be found. I have no clue what to do.

Comment: What do you mean 'copied over the SDK files'? you have an installer for that. [Win SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)

Comment: I wasnt able to install that sdk on the Virtual Machine because it kept failing. So I copied over the sdk that I was using from my development machine and entered the keys in the registry

Comment: Doing installer tasks manually is never a good idea. Unless you're absolutely sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: I understand that but, overtime i run these install it fails, plus to run the rebuild for an excel add in is the only thing i need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your environment variable path includes the folder in which ResGen.exe resides

Comment: If your speaking of path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\
Windows\v7.0A InstallationFoldr, to make sure resgen.exe is in the bin folder it is initially it was labeled "ResGen.exe" I renamed it "resgen.exe" and it is still giving me the same message

Comment: zTo COnt: the resgen.exe executuable was in the bin folder. Otherwise can you explain how to get the enviornment variables?

Answer (score 3):

I added the following SdkToolPath parameter to the project and that helped. Of course it is not a full solution as it will not work on the buildserver, but for now it works and I just don't check it in from my machine and it means I can do what I need to:

```
<GenerateResource SdkToolsPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools" Sources="@(TextResource)" OutputResources="@(TextResource->'$(OutDir)CommandStrings.resources')" />
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day. The misleading error messages states about "Pass the correct location into the "ToolPath" parameter of the task" - `ToolPath` cannot  be recognized by `GenerateResource` task, `SdkToolsPath` is, Shame on you Microsoft!

Answer (score 2):

Run Regedit to edit your registry. Look for the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows. If there is not already a Setting called "CurrentVersion", create a new registry setting "CurrentVersion" of type REG_SZ. Make sure it has the same value as the setting ProductionVersion in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A.

Make sure, you have the keys HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\WinSDK-NetFX40Tools, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\WinSDK-NetFX40Tools-x86 and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\WinSDK-NetFX40Tools-x64 present in your registry and the value InstallationFolder set in each of them.